# Regex to extract string between the 2nd instance of one character and the 2nd instance of another

Tags: regex

I want to extract `a.test` from a field with the following structure: `this-is-a.test.sentence`, meaning the result starts at the second instance of `-` and ends at the second instance of `.` non-inclusive. I can see how to achieve this when the characters are the same, but not when they're different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `^.*?-.*?-(.*?\..*?)\.`

Explanation:

```
^    : [^] represents the beginning of the string
.*?- : [.] is any character except line breaks, 
       [*] matches 0 or more (aka optional), 
       [?] makes it lazy meaning it will match as few characters as possible.
       [-] matches a literal '-' character
.*?-.*?- : doing this pattern twice will match the following: '--', 'ANY-THING-', '-ANYTHING-', 
                                                              'TWO-DASHES-', 'TWODASHES--', etc.

(.*?\..*?)\. : ( ) wrapping a pattern makes it a capture group used to easily pull what you need
              [.*?] - same as above (lazy, optional character(s))
              [\.]  - escaped literal '.' character (#1)
              [.*?] - same as above (lazy, optional character(s)) again
              [\.]  - escaped literal '.' character (#2) - notice it's outside our capture group 
                                                           to make it non-inclusive
```

Using this, your desired string `--.some.thing.` will return anything from the first dot to the second instance of a dot, only capturing the first dot. Strings are only matched if there are two dashes and two or more dots *after* the dashes. Here are some tests:

```
this-is-a.test.sentence -- matches // group 1: 'a.test'
any-thing-some.thing.cool -- matches // group 1: 'some.thing'

anything-some.thing.cool -- doesn't match because there is only one dash 
any-thing-some.thingcool -- doesn't match because there is only one dot
any.thing-some.thing-cool -- doesn't match because the dashes and dots are out of order.
```

Answer (score 0):

`^.*?-.*?-(.*?\..*?)\.` will be the correct regex in this case.

Explanation:

`^` matches the start of the string

`.*?-` matches anything until the first/second `-`

`(.*?\..*?)\.` will anything until a `.`, then a `.` literally and afterwards anything until the next `.`